# Cookies not working while viewing a dev version of a Next app on a mobile device

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mobile

I have been testing my Next JS development build on a mobile phone, accessing it via a private IP address, i.e. 192.XXX.X.24:3000, instead of localhost:3000 that I use on my development machine. The pages are all loading just fine, however, whenever I need to communicate cookies back to my back end, it turns out that my phone is storing no cookies (or at least is sending none). If I visit my local IP address instead of localhost on my development machine, the issue is replicated - no cookies are being sent sent to the backend.

I know that I can simulate the mobile device screen size in dev tools, but I get a much better feel for the UX while viewing on an actual mobile screen.

Is there a way to tackle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, the cookies were blocked, because the cookies sent from my API were marked as samesite: true, hence it was impossible to pass the from api operating on a localhost address to my private IP address. Changing the cookies on the back end to samesite: false made them work.